# Broken ubuntu installation doesnt booting

Tags: ubuntu, boot

My local Ubuntu 7.10 dev server was unresponsive the other day so I rebooted it and now I can't boot into it.

I can boot into the Live CD and mount my hdd so I can have a look at the logs and what not. 
`/var/log/messages` has a lot of entries like this;

```
jun 9 09:32:55 mccoy -- MARK --
```

Then it has a few like this;

```
jun 9 09:15:30 mccoy kernel [92923832.32322332] res 09 90 989 78 67 56 Emask 0x2 (HSM Violation) [Not exact numbers]
```

When I boot, I get to a busybox shell after a message saying /dev/md2 doesn't exist.

I would be really appreciative for any help, this box runs a few things for the office and they're all down atm.

Comment: What is on /dev/md2 on your system?

Answer (score 3):

Get into your command line when it boots, and run:

```
mdadm --assemble --scan
```

This should scan for parts of raid drives and allow the md device to mount.

Then check by doing

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md2
```

You can then check

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

Reboot.

*You should* post what type of md you have and level, how many disks too?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've got a md-raid that's failing to reassemble itself for root.  get to that busybox shell and look in /proc/md* and look up how to use the mdadm command to try and reconstitute your array.